# How to do a union rolling window on a GeoDataFrame

Tags: geopandas

I want to get a new `GeoDataFrame` in which each element is the union of `N` consecutive elements in my original `GeoDataFrame`.
I'd be very happy if this code worked, but it doesn't: the last step fails.

```py
from shapely.geometry import Polygon
from shapely.ops import unary_union
import geopandas as gpd

p1 = Polygon([(1,1),(1,2),(2,2)])
p2 = Polygon([(1,1),(2,2),(2,1)])
p3 = Polygon([(1,1),(2,1),(2,0)])
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=[p1, p2, p3])

gdf.rolling(window=2).apply(unary_union)
```

I would expect something that behaves like this

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'numbers': [1,2,3]})
df.rolling(window=2).apply(sum)

Out[1]: 
   numbers
0      NaN
1      3.0
2      5.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve it like this:

```
from shapely.geometry import Polygon
from shapely.ops import unary_union
import geopandas as gpd
import numpy as np

p1 = Polygon([(1,1),(1,2),(2,2)])
p2 = Polygon([(1,1),(2,2),(2,1)])
p3 = Polygon([(1,1),(2,1),(2,0)])
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=[p1, p2, p3])

#gdf.rolling(window=2).apply(unary_union)
#DataError: Cannot aggregate non-numeric type: geometry

rolling_window = gdf.rolling(window=2)

#Create a list of lists with geometry pairs in each sublist
geometry_pairs = [[*l.geometry] for l in rolling_window if len(l) == 2] #https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70670079/get-indexes-of-pandas-rolling-window
unions = [unary_union(pair) for pair in geometry_pairs]
unions.insert(0, np.nan)

 # [nan,
 # <POLYGON ((1 2, 2 2, 2 1, 1 1, 1 2))>,
 # <POLYGON ((2 0, 1 1, 2 2, 2 1, 2 0))>]
```